# 5318008 - Fun with Calculators

Tags: code-golf

In schools across the world, children type a number into their LCD calculator, turn it upside down and erupt into laughter after creating the word 'Boobies'. Of course, this is the most popular word, but there are many other words which can be produced.

All words must be less than 10 letters long, however (the dictionary does contain words long than this however, so you must perform a filter in your program). In this dictionary, there are some uppercase words, so convert the all words the lowercase.

Using, an English language dictionary, create a list of numbers which can be typed into an LCD calculator and makes a word. As with all code golf questions, the shortest program to complete this task wins.

For my tests, I used the UNIX wordlist, gathered by typing:

```
ln -s /usr/dict/words w.txt
```

Or alternatively, get it [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/eneko/data-repository/master/data/words.txt).

[image]

For example, the image above was created by typing the number `35007` into the calculator and turning it upside down.

The letters and their respective numbers:

- *b*: `8`
- *g*: `6`
- *l*: `7`
- *i*: `1`
- *o*: `0`
- *s*: `5`
- *z*: `2`
- *h*: `4`
- *e*: `3`

Note that if the number starts with a zero, a decimal point is required after that zero. The number must not start with a decimal point.

I think this is MartinBüttner's code, just wanted to credit you for it :)

```js
/* Configuration */

var QUESTION_ID = 51871; // Obtain this from the url
// It will be like http://XYZ.stackexchange.com/questions/QUESTION_ID/... on any question page
var ANSWER_FILTER = "!t)IWYnsLAZle2tQ3KqrVveCRJfxcRLe";

/* App */

var answers = [], page = 1;

function answersUrl(index) {
  return "http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/" +  QUESTION_ID + "/answers?page=" + index + "&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter=" + ANSWER_FILTER;
}

function getAnswers() {
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: answersUrl(page++),
    method: "get",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function (data) {
      answers.push.apply(answers, data.items);
      if (data.has_more) getAnswers();
      else process();
    }
  });
}

getAnswers();

var SIZE_REG = /\d+(?=[^\d&]*(?:&lt;(?:s&gt;[^&]*&lt;\/s&gt;|[^&]+&gt;)[^\d&]*)*$)/;
var NUMBER_REG = /\d+/;
var LANGUAGE_REG = /^#*\s*([^,]+)/;

function shouldHaveHeading(a) {
  var pass = false;
  var lines = a.body_markdown.split("\n");
  try {
    pass |= /^#/.test(a.body_markdown);
    pass |= ["-", "="]
              .indexOf(lines[1][0]) > -1;
    pass &= LANGUAGE_REG.test(a.body_markdown);
  } catch (ex) {}
  return pass;
}

function shouldHaveScore(a) {
  var pass = false;
  try {
    pass |= SIZE_REG.test(a.body_markdown.split("\n")[0]);
  } catch (ex) {}
  return pass;
}

function getAuthorName(a) {
  return a.owner.display_name;
}

function process() {
  answers = answers.filter(shouldHaveScore)
                   .filter(shouldHaveHeading);
  answers.sort(function (a, b) {
    var aB = +(a.body_markdown.split("\n")[0].match(SIZE_REG) || [Infinity])[0],
        bB = +(b.body_markdown.split("\n")[0].match(SIZE_REG) || [Infinity])[0];
    return aB - bB
  });

  var languages = {};
  var place = 1;
  var lastSize = null;
  var lastPlace = 1;
  answers.forEach(function (a) {
    var headline = a.body_markdown.split("\n")[0];
    //console.log(a);
    var answer = jQuery("#answer-template").html();
    var num = headline.match(NUMBER_REG)[0];
    var size = (headline.match(SIZE_REG)||[0])[0];
    var language = headline.match(LANGUAGE_REG)[1];
    var user = getAuthorName(a);
    if (size != lastSize)
      lastPlace = place;
    lastSize = size;
    ++place;
    answer = answer.replace("{{PLACE}}", lastPlace + ".")
                   .replace("{{NAME}}", user)
                   .replace("{{LANGUAGE}}", language)
                   .replace("{{SIZE}}", size)
                   .replace("{{LINK}}", a.share_link);
    answer = jQuery(answer)
    jQuery("#answers").append(answer);

    languages[language] = languages[language] || {lang: language, user: user, size: size, link: a.share_link};
  });

  var langs = [];
  for (var lang in languages)
    if (languages.hasOwnProperty(lang))
      langs.push(languages[lang]);

  langs.sort(function (a, b) {
    if (a.lang > b.lang) return 1;
    if (a.lang < b.lang) return -1;
    return 0;
  });

  for (var i = 0; i < langs.length; ++i)
  {
    var language = jQuery("#language-template").html();
    var lang = langs[i];
    language = language.replace("{{LANGUAGE}}", lang.lang)
                       .replace("{{NAME}}", lang.user)
                       .replace("{{SIZE}}", lang.size)
                       .replace("{{LINK}}", lang.link);
    language = jQuery(language);
    jQuery("#languages").append(language);
  }

}
```

```css
body { text-align: left !important}

#answer-list {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}

#language-list {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 50%px;
  float: left;
}

table thead {
  font-weight: bold;
}

table td {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/codegolf/all.css?v=83c949450c8b">
<div id="answer-list">
  <h2>Leaderboard</h2>
  <table class="answer-list">
    <thead>
      <tr><td></td><td>Author</td><td>Language</td><td>Size</td></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="answers">

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<div id="language-list">
  <h2>Winners by Language</h2>
  <table class="language-list">
    <thead>
      <tr><td>Language</td><td>User</td><td>Score</td></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="languages">

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<table style="display: none">
  <tbody id="answer-template">
    <tr><td>{{PLACE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table style="display: none">
  <tbody id="language-template">
    <tr><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Do we assume all words in the wordlist are less than 10 letters, or do we filter that out ourselves?

Comment: @ASCIIThenANSI You must filter this yourself

Comment: Doesn't detract from the question, but note that the calculator in the image has only 8 digits available in its display...

Comment: And can the decimal point be placed after the ninth letter (I'm assuming 9 letters is the maximum)?

Comment: Can use a decimal point after the first number even if it isn't required?

Comment: Do we have to type `0.7734` for *hello* or would `.7734` be acceptable?

Comment: What is the correct behaviour if the dictionary contains words with upper case, punctuation, etc?

Comment: @Dennis `0.7734` is required

Comment: It seems the linked dictionary has duplicate words for upper case and lower case. IMO, it is better to ignore the upper case words to avoid double counting.

Comment: What about words that require a trailing zero after the decimal?  For example, `oligo` requires a trailing zero *after* the decimal: `0.6170`

Comment: Are we allowed to output the numbers as a list? As in, something like `[3,7,0,4]` for 'hole'?

Comment: @M. I. Wright No, sorry

Comment: I always liked the `707 + 707 = 1414` (`lol + lol = hihi`)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## CJam, <s>44</s> 42 bytes

```
r{el"oizehsglb"f#W%"0."a.e|N+_,B<*_W&!*r}h
```

Try it online in the [CJam interpreter](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=r%7Bel%22oizehsglb%22f%23W%25%220.%22a.e%7CN%2B_%2CB%3C*_W%26!*r%7Dh&input=Bill%0Ahohohohoho%0Ahello%0Abye).

To run the program from the command line, download the [Java interpreter](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam/wiki/Home/) and execute:

```
java -jar cjam-0.6.5.jar 5318008.cjam < /usr/share/dict/words
```

#### How it works

```
r            e# Read a whitespace-separated token from STDIN.
{            e# While loop:
 el          e#   Convert to lowercase.
 "oizehsglb" e#   Push that string.
 f#          e#   Get the index of each character from the input in that string.
             e#   This pushes -1 for "not found".
 W%          e#   Reverse the resulting array.
 "0."a       e#   Push ["0."].
 .e|         e#   Vectorized logical NOT. This replaces an initial 0 with "0.".
 N+          e#   Append a linefeed.
 _,B<*       e#   Repeat the array (array.length < 11) times.
 _W&!*       e#   Repeat the array !(array.intersection(-1)) times.
 r           e#   Read a whitespace-separated token from STDIN.
}h           e# If the token is not empty, repeat the loop.
```

Answer (score 9):

## Bash + coreutils, 54

Again, thanks to @TobySpeight for the golfing help.

```
rev|tr oizehsglb 0-8|sed '/.\{11\}\|[^0-9]/d;s/^0/&./'
```

Input wordlist is taken from STDIN:

```
$ ./5318008.sh < /usr/share/dict/words | head
8
38
338
5338
638
5638
36138
31738
531738
7738
$
```

Comment: "Belie" and "Belies" are words? The more you know...

Answer (score 6):

## Python 2, <s>271</s> <s>216</s> <s>211</s> 205 Bytes

This is the only idea I've had so far.. I will update this once I think of something else! I assumed we needed to read from a file, but if not let me know so I can update :)

*Big thanks to Dennis for saving me 55 bytes :)*

*Also thanks to Sp3000 for saving 6 bytes :)*

```python
d,f,g='oizehsglb',[x.lower()for x in open('w.txt').read().split('\n')if len(x)<10],[]
for x in f:
 c=x[::-1]
 for b in d:c=c.replace(b,`d.find(b)`)
 g=[g,g+[['0.'+c[1:],c][c[0]!='0']]][c.isdigit()]
print g
```

Comment: I don't know a lot of Python, but wouldn't something like `"oizehsglb".index(b)` be shorter?

Comment: I'm not sure how you want to implement that.. getting the index of where one of these characters is doesn't really help in this case since I just need to replace all instances.

Comment: `d[b] == "oizehsglb".index(b)`. Possibly lacking a cast to string/character.

Comment: Oh, wow, it never occurred to me that the numbers we were able to replace had numerical values in order.. Yes, that will definitely work! Thanks!

Comment: Haven't tested but: 1) `.find` is shorter than `.index`, 2) Depending on which version you have, at least in 2.7.10 `open` without a mode argument defaults to `r`, 3) Doesn't just `for x in open(...)` work? (may need to remove a trailing newline) If it doesn't, then `.split('\n')` is shorter than `.splitlines()`

Comment: @Sp3000 1) Thanks, forgot about that. 2) Didn't know that was the case! 3) just `open(...)` didn't work, so I changed to `.split('\n')`. Thanks!

Comment: Just tried - `open(...)` works, but you do need to account for the trailing newline, so you'd need `[x[:-1].lower()for x in open('w.txt')if len(x)<11]`.

Comment: Also `g+=[['0.'+c[1:],c][c[0]!='0']]*c.isdigit()`, and you can save a few more by reversing in `f` then doing `for c in f` instead of having `c=x[::-1]`. Also you only use `f` once, so you don't need to save it as a variable

Answer (score 6):

## JavaScript (ES7), 73 bytes

This can be done in ES7 a mere 73 bytes:

```
s=>[for(w of s)'oizehsglb'.search(w)].reverse().join``.replace(/^0/,'0.')
```

Ungolfed:

```
var b = function b(s) {
    return s.length < 10 && /^[bglioszhe]*$/.test(s) ? s.replace(/./g, function (w) {
        return 'oizehsglb'.search(w);
    }).reverse().join('').replace(/^0/, '0.') : '';
};
```

Usage:

```
t('hello'); // 0.7734
t('loose'); // 35007
t('impossible'); //
```

Function:

```
t=s=>                       // Create a function 't' with an argument named 's' 
   [                        // Return this array  comprehension
     for(i of s)            // Loops through each letter in the string
     'oizehsglb'.search(w)  // Converts it to it's corresponding number
   ]
  .reverse().join``         // Reverse the array and make it a string
  .replace(/^0/,'0.')       // If the first character is a 0, add a decimal after it
```

---

I ran this on the UNIX wordlist and have put the results in a paste bin:

## [Results](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=B8ZaGaDj)

The code used to obtain the results *on Firefox*:

```
document.querySelector('pre').innerHTML.split('\n').map(i => t(i.toLowerCase())).join('\n').replace(/^\s*[\r\n]/gm, '');
```

Comment: What happens with `t('Impossible')`?

Comment: @ArturoTorresSánchez You're right, I've fixed that

Comment: is join`` ES2015 or is it pre-ES2015?

Comment: @WallyWest That's an ES6 feature. It's supported in most major browsers

Comment: What is ES7 specific in this?

Comment: @Sting `[for(... of ...)]` syntax is ES7. Though it's really only supported in Firefox

Answer (score 5):

## Python 2, 121 bytes

```py
for s in open("w.txt"):
 L=map("oizehsglb".find,s[-2::-1].lower())
 if-min(L)<1>len(L)-9:print`L[0]`+"."[L[0]:]+`L`[4::3]
```

Assumes that the dictionary file `w.txt` ends with a trailing newline, and has no empty lines.

Answer (score 3):

## GNU sed, 82

(including 1 for `-r`)

Thanks to @TobySpeight for the golfing help.

```
s/$/:/
:
s/(.)(:.*)/\2\1/
t
s/://
y/oizehsglb/012345678/
/.{11}|[^0-9]/d;s/^0/&./
```

Input wordlist is taken from STDIN:

```
$ sed -rf 5318008.sed /usr/share/dict/words | tail
3705
53705
1705
0.705
50705
5705
505
2
0.02
5002
$
```

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2, <s>147</s> <s>158</s> 156 bytes

I was missing this '0.' requirement. Hope now it works allright.

**edit**: Removed ".readlines()" and it still works ;p

**edit2**: Removed some spaces and move print to the 3rd line

**edit3**: Saved 2 bytes thanks to Sp3000 (removed space after print and changed 'index' to 'find')

```py
for x in open("w.txt"):
 a="oizehsglb";g=[`a.find(b)`for b in x[::-1].lower()if b in a]
 if len(g)==len(x)-1<10:
  if g[0]=="0":g[0]="0."
  print"".join(g)
```

Answer (score 1):

## C, <strike>182</strike> <strike>172</strike>  <strike>169/181</strike> 172 bytes

```
char*l="oizehsglb",S[99],*s,*t;main(x){for(;t=S+98,gets(S);){for(s=S;*s;s++)if(x=strchr(l,*s|32))*--t=48+x-(int)l;else break;*t==48?*t--=46,*t=48:0;*s||s-S>10?0:puts(t);}}
```

Expanded

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *l="oizehsglb",S[99],*s,*t;

main(int x, char **argv)
{
    for (;t=S+98,gets(S);){
        for (s=S;*s;s++)
            if (x=strchr(l,*s|32))
                *--t=48+x-(int)l;
            else
                break;
        if (*t==48) {       // '0'
            *t--=46;        // '.'
            *t=48;  // '0'
        }

        if (!*s && s-S <= 10)
            puts(t);
    }
}
```

using the linked words.txt, with lower case conversion:

```
$ ./a.out  < words.txt  | tail
2212
0.2
0.802
0.602
7702
37702
0.02
321607002
515002
0.02002

$ ./a.out < words.txt   | wc -l
 550
```

Comment: Won't `*s|32` work as lowercase conversion in this context?

Comment: Great idea! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby 2, <s>88</s> 86 bytes

```
x="oizehsglb"
puts$_.tr(x,"0-8").reverse.sub /^0/,"0." if$_.size<11&&$_.delete(x)<?A
```

Byte count includes 2 for the `ln` options on the command line:

```
$ ruby -ln 5318008.rb wordlist.txt
```

Comment: In this case `==""` can be replaced with `<?A`. And no need for `gsub()` as `sub()` is enough.

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2, <s>184</s> 174 bytes

```
for s in open('w.txt'):
 try:a=''.join(map(lambda c:dict(zip('bglioszhe','867105243'))[c],s[:-1][::-1]));a=[a,'0.'+a[1:]][a[0]=='0'];print['',''.join(a)][len(s)<11]
 except:0
```

Answer (score 1):

## Java, <strike>208</strike> <strike>200</strike> 176 bytes

```
String f(char[] w){String o="",l="oizehsglb";for(int i=w.length;i>0;i--)o+=l.indexOf(w[i-1]|32);if(o.contains("-")||o.length()>8)o="  ";return o.charAt(0)+"."+o.substring(1);}
```

Expanded

```
String f(char[] w)
{
    String o = "", l = "oizehsglb";
    for(int i = w.length; i > 0; i--)
        o+=l.indexOf(w[i-1]|32);
    if(o.contains("-")||o.length() > 8)
        o = "  ";
    return o.charAt(0) + "." + o.substring(1);
}
```

It always adds the decimal, and when invalid returns " . ". But otherwise works like it should. :P

Thanks  @LegionMammal978!

Comment: You can save 7 bytes by changing `;String l=` to `,l=` and `=o+` to `+=`.

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell, 175 bytes without imports (229 bytes with imports)

Relevant code (say in File Calc.hs):

```
import Data.Char(toLower)
import Data.Maybe(mapMaybe)
s="oizehsglb\n"
g('0':r)="0."++r
g x=x
main=mapM_(putStrLn.g.reverse.mapMaybe(`lookup`zip s['0'..'8'])).filter(\l->length l<10&&all(`elem`s)l).lines.map toLower=<<getContents

$ cat /usr/share/dict/words | runghc Calc.hs
```